# Querying database with uknown amout of parameters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my situation. I'm developing a small helpdesk where the user will do a search of their problem. E.G. `I cannot connect to the internet`.

I have on my database a table for keywords, such a internet, connection, internet-explorer, etc.

What I want to do is split that sentence, `I cannot connect to the internet` into words and have an array:

```
[0]=> I
[1]=> cannot
[2]=> connect
[3]=> to
[4]=> the
[5]=> internet
```

And then make a query on the database, very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM solutions T1 
  join solution_tags_intermediate T2 on T1.ID_SOLUTION = T2.ID_SOLUTION  
  join solution_tags T3 on T2.SOLUTION_TAGS_ID = T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_ID 
  WHERE T3. SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME = ??
```

Here is my problem, how can I bring a list of records back from the database that match my search when I do not know the exact amount of parameters until the query is executed?

Is there a way to do this or a more elaborate one?

By the way this is being developed on php and mysql.

Comment: Is the T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME supposed to be one of the items in the array?  Can you do `WHERE T3. SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME IN ('".implode("','",$array)."')`  -- This is vulnerable, but you can do a count, and replace it with `?` to make it secure...  But is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: You'd be better off using a `FULLTEXT` index, and stripping out "noise" words like `To` and `the` before doing the search

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do a search related to any of the words in that string. Can you do a more elaborated example please?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use explode() and fputcsv() to split the search phrase into an array and then convert that to a comma delimited string. You can then use an IN clause in your query to do the search.

WHERE T3.SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME IN (".$csv_variable.")";

Comment: how does the fputcsv() function work? Haven't use that one before. According to PHP documentation, it created a CSV file, why would I want to create one?

Comment: Actually it should have been implode instead of fputcsv, sorry about that. The concept is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously consider following @MarcB comment advice.  This is what fulltext searches were made for.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: I read the article but I'm a little confused. How would my query change if I were to usefulltext search?